# Подключение header и footer к странице метод

Tags: html

Коллеги, всем привет.
Нашел способ подключения блоков на страницу как отдельных файлов с расширением .html
Выглядит это так -
В необходимое место на странице вставляем код:

```
<!--#include file="./footer.html" -->
```

Кто может подсказать, будет ли такой метод нормально работать и не возникнет ли каких-нибудь с ним проблем.
Знаю, что есть масса других способов, но интересует именно этот.

Спасибо

Comment: Это называется SSI (Server Side Includes), будет работать, если сервер настроен соответствующим образом.

Comment: @Simon спасибо большое за ответ!